# Rails concerns, how to include a concern inside an api controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, activesupport-concern

I am building a Rails api and currently have this folder structure:

[image]

The error_serializer.rb file is a module:

```
module ErrorSerializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  ...methods here...
end
```

Which I can include in any of the api controllers, for example:

```
class Api::TemplatesController < ApiController
  include ErrorSerializer
  ...
end
```

But since this errors_serializer module is only relevant to api controllers, I want to move the file to '`api/concerns/error_serializer.rb`'.

But that generates the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::TemplatesController::ErrorSerializer)
```

I tried changing the name inside the file to:

```
module Api::ErrorSerialzer
```

but got the same error.

So what must I change to be able to move that file?

Comment: Did you change the `include` to be `Api::ErrorSerializer`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes I did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since rails expects your module naming to follow your file structure, your concern should be named:

```
module Api::Concerns::ErrorSerializer
```

Since you're including it in `Api::TemplatesController`, I would do:

```
class Api::TemplatesController < ApiController
  include Api::Concerns::ErrorSerializer
  ...
end
```

To help rails out with the constant lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from @jvillian and [this blog post](http://jordifierro.com/rails-apicontroller-and-concerns), I was able to figure out the 'Rails' way to do this (since actually I will need the concern in all Api controllers, and also my api controller was outside the api namespace). So I'm posting this solution as (I think) it's the preferred way:

I moved the error_serialzier.rb file into api/concerns and change the code to include the Api namespace:

```
module Api::Concerns::ErrorSerializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  ...
end
```

I also moved `api_controller.rb` file and put it inside the /api folder, and thus into the API module namespace, so now it looks like this:

```
class Api::ApiController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_api_user!
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken 
  include Concerns::ErrorSerializer

  respond_to :json
end
```

This got rid of the uninitialized constant errors.

Comment: Do you know how to include error_serializer.rb if error_serializer.rb file is not in /api/concerns, but still in /concerns?

Comment: @ToshihiroYokota I don't work in Rails any more, but try `include Concerns::ErrorSerializer`

Comment: @rmcharry It just worked. I understand it works if I recognize "rails expects your module naming to follow your file structure". Thanks for that.

Comment: @ToshihiroYokota Good to hear it worked, thanks for letting me know! :)